# Machine comms troubleshooting

Tags: digital-communications

While this may be suited for an automotive section I believe my question is better suited to this forum.

I'm having OBD II comms issues and have a run a similar troubleshooting process to what's listed here.

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44157/obd-ii-scanner-refuses-to-communicate-with-the-vehicle

In addition I have checked the actual voltages and grounding of the data link connector (DLC).

Per the following I have J1850 PWM pin out.

http://www.onboarddiagnostics.com/page03.htm

I am relatively new new to electronical comms processes having only tinkered with an arduino. My voltages are 12v at the battery and pin 16 to pins 4+5. Pin 2 to ground varies between 1.5v-2.1v, pin 10 to ground varies between 4.3v and 3.5v.

Not sure if I am accurately reading pins for a coms protocol should I be measuring voltage between the +bus and -bus or between the bus and ground?

If my measurmemts are accurate does it indicate a wiring problem or a comms ouput issue?

"-Edit your question with more details. What OBD cable you have? Have you been able to make it work somewhere? What software are you using? What car or CAN device are you trying to connect to? What other resources you have available or you might be able to get?"

I was using a [Veepeak OBDII BTLE connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073XKQQQW). I have also used [A cheap advance version](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/actron-pocketscan-plus-abs-obd-ii-and-can-cp9660/11022471-P?searchTerm=OBD%20II%20reader) and [the more expensive advance version](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/actron-elite-autoscanner-kit-enhanced-obd-i-and-obd-ii-scan-tool-cp9690/11022315-P?searchTerm=OBD%20II%20reader), in addition a mechanic tried to use their professional computer for inspections and it failed there.

I have used all of these OBD connectors to connect to other vehicles. I have used both torque pro and car scanner apps for the bluetooth. The other scan tools come with whatever default software they are running.

I am attempting to connect to a 2003 Mazda Tribute ES  V6 3.0L engine.

Since writing the original post I have swapped the ECU, which brought the voltage outputs in spec range, and bypassed the DLC using some spare jumpers I had soldered to alligator clips and then form fit O ring style connectors to the pins on the OBD reader.

I'm more than willing to get another arduio shield and learn a bit more but as far as I can tell the car doesn't speak CAN. J1850 PWM is it's own pin out and comms protocol that was common on early Fords, Mazdas and related production.

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent issues you will find while troubleshooting communication buses are:

-**Hardware**: cables not connected correctly (number one when you have multiple pin connectors like your case) or the wrong type of cable (impedance not correct) or there is no termination when it should be.

-**Configuration**: Different settings on either side, like baudrates or protocols.

For your CAN bus network in particular, you don't give much information on the tools you are using and trying to diagnose based on bus voltages only is quite difficult.

My advice is to follow one of these routes:

-Get yourself an oscilloscope and look at the signals on the bus. Even if you don't have experience you can find a lot of resources online. [This](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt529/slyt529.pdf) is a good starting point.

-Switch off the power of all devices on the network and take a look at resistances. See, for instance, a short guide [here](https://www.esd-electronics-usa.com/Shared/Library/CAN-Troubleshooting-Guide.pdf).

-Check both sides of the communication bus independently. If you're using an OBD cable test it somewhere else (for instance another car that you know was working properly or a dummy testing device). If you don't have additional tools this might seem difficult or expensive but nowadays you can get very cheap [hardware](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13262) and you would save a lot of time. Better to have more devices and tools than you need than waste hours or days hitting a wall.

-Edit your question with more details. What OBD cable you have? Have you been able to make it work somewhere? What software are you using? What car or CAN device are you trying to connect to? What other resources you have available or you might be able to get?